# Need Help : BackToPop stack management

Tags: android

i am newbie in android
Following is my senerio please help me in that:

I have one button in main activity named as "Back" which will be visible for all the Fragments now i want that if i am in my first fragment and and if i navigate from firstfragment to secondFragment when i click "Back" Button from secondFragment then i should be navigate to fist fragment..
Remind i have button in main activity

I am getting confused about this for manage backpress events..

I am trying following code also but nothing gets works

### case R.id.btnBack: Log.v("Calling......events","ok"); FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); fm.popBackStack (tagToSet, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); //onBackPressed(); break;

Please help me

Comment: please share full code

Comment: I dont have code written.. i am looking for code...

Comment: Having "Back" Button in MainActivity and having fragment to display but now Naviagte from fragment1-Fragment2 and if i clicked "Back" Button (Main activity display on top of each fragment) then i should be navigate to fragment 1.. how to do that

Comment: so basically onBackButtonPressed( ) will pop out top fragment which is present in stack. so basically you have to implement the same thing to your on button click, just remove the top-fragment from stack

Comment: Thanks for reply now my another question is as my back button is common for all fragemnt then how should i come to know that which fragemnt i need to remove from my stack

Comment: It depends on how you are using your fragments ?? I mean at a time only one fragment is visible to user that is it is on the top of stack ?